# How to upload files in selenium webdriver-python without input tag,Sendkeys

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to make sending naver email automation python scripts, and one thing that I can't do is upload file without SendKeys method(even have not to input tags(elements). and I searched in google there have only uploaded a file with input tags. plz, help me.

I'm tried to code by sendkeys but the error is selenium.common.exceptions,ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

```
    # Attachment 
    if attach:
    attach = config.attachment

    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="write_drag_here"]').send_keys('path in here')
    print('attachment activated')
    time.sleep(10)
    else:
    print('attachment deactivated')
```

How can I code this HTML
*HTML CODE:**

```
    <a href="#" id="AddButton_fla" class="utx_btn_b _c1(mwAttach|clickUpload) 
    _stopDefault" onclick="ccr(this,'wrh.attach',event)" style="display: none;"> 
    <span class="utx_inrbtn">내 PC</span></a>
    <a href="#" id="AddButton_html5" class="utx_btn_b 
    _click(mwAttach|clickHtml5Upload) _stopDefault" 
    onclick="ccr(this,'wh5.attach',event)" style="display: inline-block;">
    <span 
    class="utx_inrbtn">내 PC</span></a>
```

**Note:** Feel free to ask me again if you can't understand anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a script is interfering with it, one way I typically do it is to use screen coordinates to interact with the Element as a user would by using a macro program like AppRobotic, and simulate mouse movements and use SendKeys only after the Element is activated on the screen:

```
import win32com.client
x = win32com.client.Dispatch("AppRobotic.API")
from selenium import webdriver

# navigate to Instagram
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.AttachmentWebsite.com') 
# sleep 1 second
x.Wait(1000)

# Move mouse to coordinates 250, 500 on the screen
x.MoveCursor(250,500)
x.MouseLeftClick
# sleep 1 second
x.Wait(1000)
x.Type("my attachment")
```